# Selenium python get attribute by class and title

Tags: selenium, xpath, screen-scraping

I have googled this extensively but can't get to an answer, I'm trying to extract "90,856" in the title. It's value changes over time:

```
<div class="card hreddeep">
<div class="card-header hbuilt">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6 text-left">
<div class="h6 text-uppercase param-title">Search<br>Volume</div>
<div class="h4 param-content" title="90,856">
```

my code is:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='h4-param-content']").get_attribute("title")
```

grateful for some help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath contains a typo (according to your sample data) : `h4-param` instead of `h4 param`...

First, test with :

```
find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='h4 param-content']").get_attribute("title")
```

If it doesn't work, try with an expected condition.

Add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
output = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='h4 param-content']"))).get_attribute("title")
print(output)
```